# Rolling samples, choosing a number of observations

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I want to estimate a forecasting equation for monthly data. I'm essentially trying to find out how to balance the stability of using a longer time series to estimate the equation versus the fact that the relationship is likely changing over time and older observations could be more of a hindrance than a help. Can anyone recommend a good paper on this or let me know how they proceed for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the estimation you want to perform. For example, estimating a correlation requires relatively few data compared to estimate precisely the distribution.

I suggest you to test the stability of your estimate. For a too short sliding window, your estimate will be unstable (since it was (over)fitted on too few data). On a too big sample, it could be rather stable since it averages over a long time, but smoothing too strongly the signal. Thus, try to find the shortest length of your sliding window that yields stable coefficients for your model/equation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I could ask one follow up, how would you recommend I test the stability?

Comment: I have no precision about your model. For instance, if it is a polynomial, then monitor the norm of the variation of its coefficients, if it is a clustering, then monitor their composition, number, etc. More generally, find summary statistics of your model, and create the time series of these statistics. If they are chaotic, either your underlying time series is very special or you fit the noise and should go for a wider moving window.